# mrt migrate-app freezes in the middle

Tags: meteor, meteorite

When I run mrt migrate-app I get a list of packages it will migrate and then it just stops and nothing happens. It doesn't go through the entire list of packages either.

Do I need to do meteor update to meteor 0.92 first or is migrate-app the first thing to do? I'm having trouble with both.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I had to run mrt migrate-app multiple times for this to work.
To update to meteor 0.9 I also had problems. Remove packages from .meteor/packages to update the app and then readd them.